# What happens if I send the same pending intent twice?

Tags: java, android, android-pendingintent

I am trying to send two pending intent lets say i sent my first intent 1 minute later and my second intent 2 minute later. I use the same action for both of them.
What happens is only the second intent works but that too 2 minutes later.

```
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(ALARM_ACTION_NAME);
        if(val1) {

            intent.putExtra("TYPE","SILENT");
        }
        else {

            intent.putExtra("TYPE", "RING" );

        }


        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2,intent, 0);
```

where the broadcast reciever is as folows...

```
if(ALARM_ACTION_NAME.equals(intent.getAction())){
            Log.i("this", intent.getStringExtra("TYPE"));
            if(intent.getStringExtra("TYPE").equals("SILENT")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "illumy set the phone to Silent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                AudioManager am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 0, 0);
                am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0 , 0);

            }
            else if (intent.getStringExtra("TYPE").equals("RING")){

                Toast.makeText(context, "Phone set the phone to Ring", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                AudioManager am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 100, 0);
                am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 30 , 0);
            }
        }
```

Comment: last intent will always replace by earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Last intent will always replace by earlier. So there are 2 solutions, one is that you define multiple action and other one (Best one) manage all call in DB.It means schedule lowest upcoming call first after its execution delete that call and get again upcoming lowest call.